# Handle inbound AMQP messages based on a header attribute (e.g. routing key)

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-amqp

I have a service, that receives AMQP messages. This service is bound to a queue, which receives all messages which match a set of routing keys.

My set up is as follows:

```java
...

private SomeController controller;

@Autowired
private SimpleMessageListenerContainer receiverContainer;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(){
     var adpater = Amqp.inboundAdapter(receiverContainer);
     return IntegrationFlows.from(adapter)
               // some transformations
               .handle(controller, "processMessage")
               .get();
}
```

This already works fine. However, now I want to handle a message with different controllers, depending on a header attribute. In this case I'd like to have a controller for each routing key. Is it also a good idea to use a single queue with multiple routing keys only to handle it differently for each key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really legit to have several bindings between an exchange and a single queue.

See more info in this tutorial: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-spring-amqp.html.

The `Amqp.inboundAdapter()` relies on the `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper.inboundMapper()` by default which populates for us an `AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY` message header before producing. So, you indeed can use a `route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY))` with appropriate `channelMapping()` for the routing key value.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a code example, incorporating [Artem Bilan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756547/artem-bilan)'s (correct) answer, because additionally to that, I had to incorporate a gateway (hinted by Artem Bilan with "appropriate `channelMapping()`).

More about why you need a gateway or in some cases a bridge, refer to this part of the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows).

My initial code snippit becomes something like the following:

```java
...

@Autowired
private FirstController firstController;

@Autowired
private SecondController secondController;

@Autowired
private SimpleMessageListenerContainer receiverContainer;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow(){
     var adpater = Amqp.inboundAdapter(receiverContainer);
     return IntegrationFlows.from(adapter)
               // some transformations
               .route(Message.class, getMessageRoutingKey(m),
                        m -> m.subFlowMapping("routingKey1", firstFlow())
                                // after the first subFlow, all further integrationflows are wrapped in a gateway
                                .subFlowMapping("routingKey2", sf -> sf.gateway(secondFlow())))
               .get();
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow firstFlow() {
      return f -> f
               // e.g. additional transformations
               .handle(firstController, "processMessageInFirstFashion");
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow secondFlow() {
      return f -> f
               // e.g. additional transformations
               .handle(secondController, "processMessageInSecondFashion");
}


private static String getMessageRoutingKey(final Message<?> message) {
       return message.getHeaders().get(AmqpHeaders.RECEIVED_ROUTING_KEY).toString();
}
```